# If/else statement within switch case

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm new to js/programming and just making a simple calculator using prompt. I'm trying to validate that what's been entered are numbers and not strings. I tried this

```
var operatorType = prompt("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide?").toLowerCase();

switch (operatorType) {
    case 'add':
        var i = prompt("Enter your first number");
        var j = prompt("Enter your second number");
        if (isNaN(i) === false) && (isNaN(j) === false) {
            document.write(i+" plus "+j+" equals "+(i+j));
        } else {
            document.write("You didn't enter two numbers.");
        }
    break;
```

As well as `if (i != 'string') && (j != 'string')` but I keep getting "Unexpected token &&". I looked it up and if/else within a case is valid so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Full code if it helps

```
var operatorType = prompt("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide?").toLowerCase();

switch (operatorType) {
    case 'add':
        var i = prompt("Enter your first number");
        var j = prompt("Enter your second number");
        if (isNaN(i) === false) && (isNaN(j) === false) {
            document.write(i+" plus "+j+" equals "+(i+j));
        } else {
            document.write("You didn't enter two numbers.");
        }
    break;

    case 'subtract':
        var i = prompt("Enter your first number");
        var j = prompt("Enter your second number");
        document.write(i+" minus "+j+" equals "+(i-j));
    break;

    case 'multiply':
        var i = prompt("Enter your first number");
        var j = prompt("Enter your second number");
        document.write(i+" multiplied by "+j+" equals "+(i*j));
    break;

    case 'divide':
        var i = prompt("Enter your first number");
        var j = prompt("Enter your second number");
        document.write(i+" divided by "+j+" equals "+(i/j));
    break;

    default:
        document.write("Please enter whether you want to add, subtract, multiply or divide.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parenthesis in the wrong spot causing the syntax error. You need to move the parenthesis in this line to change from:

```
if (isNaN(i) === false) && (isNaN(j) === false) {
```

So that it becomes:

```
if (isNaN(i) === false && (isNaN(j) === false)) {
```

You'll also need to convert the strings to numbers so that your code truly adds/etc instead of concatenates the text.

Comment: Oh strange. Okay. The parenthesis seem unintuitive to me but they work. Thanks!

Comment: It's really because the `if` requires a parenthesis around the entire expression. All you really need is: `if (isNaN(i) === false && isNaN(j) === false)`. What you had was basically `if (A) && (B)`, so the javascript can't be parsed without both expressions being in a single parenthesis, like `if (A && (B))` like above,.

Comment: Okay gotcha. `if ((isNaN(i) === false) && (isNaN(j) === false))` and `if (isNaN(i) === false && isNaN(j) === false)` make sense, the unevenness was just a little confusing. Which is better to use?

Comment: For readability, I usually wrap each part in parenthesis, especially if you have longer expressions.

Comment: It is rare, although sometimes required, that `==/===` should be used with true/false. Compare with `if (!isNaN(i) && !isNaN(j)) {` which will have the same effect.